# Python output the value of the variable whose name was entered in the input

Tags: python

The user enters a variable name into the input form and I want to see its value

```
a = 20
b = 3
c = 32
d = 63

name = input("Variable name:") #FOR EXAMPLE "b"
print(name) #PRINT 3
```

Comment: Don't do this. Use a dictionary instead

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
>>> x = 1
>>> 
>>> s = 'x'
>>> s
'x'
>>> eval(s)
1
```

use eval function:

```
a = 20
name = input("Variable name:") 
print(eval(name))
```

result:

```
20
```

Comment: You should not do this, it is a bad practice, and potentially very unsafe

Answer (score 2):

I solved it in the following way:

```
dict = {
  "a": 20,
  "b": 3,
  "c": 32,
  "d": 63
}
name = input("Name:")
print(dict[name])
```

Answer (score 2):

user_value = {
"a": 20,
"b": 3,
"c": 32,
"d": 63
}

name_value = input(" Name  : ")

print("Your Entered value is : "dict[name])

Answer (score 1):

using `globals()`

```
a = 20
b = 3
c = 32
d = 63
name = input("Variable name:") #FOR EXAMPLE "b"
print(globals()[name])
```

output

```
Variable name:b
3
```